# unable to access google spreedsheets values using php

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I'm installed
    google api for OAuth2 php lib; here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/
    google spreadsheet api php lib; here: https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

created the credentials on the API Console using service account https://console.developers.google.com/

Here is the php script I used in combination with the above:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 
require_once('vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php'); 
require_once('vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'); 
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;
use Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService;

const G_CLIENT_ID       = 'my_client_id';
const G_CLIENT_EMAIL    = 'email address';
const G_CLIENT_KEY_PATH = 'key.p12';
const G_CLIENT_KEY_PW   = 'notasecret';


$obj_client_auth  = new Google_Client ();
$obj_client_auth -> setApplicationName ('newproject');
$obj_client_auth -> setClientId (G_CLIENT_ID);
$obj_client_auth -> setAssertionCredentials (new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials (
    G_CLIENT_EMAIL, 
    array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://docs.google.com/feeds'), 
    file_get_contents (G_CLIENT_KEY_PATH), 
    G_CLIENT_KEY_PW
));
$obj_client_auth -> getAuth () -> refreshTokenWithAssertion ();
$obj_token  = json_decode ($obj_client_auth -> getAccessToken ());
$accessToken = $obj_token->access_token;
$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('NewSpreadSheet');
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle('sssNew Worksheet');
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();
$row = array('name'=>'John', 'age'=>25);
```

I receive the following error:
    Call to a member function getWorksheets() on a non-object...
    I'm not getting how correct it...
    Any help n suggestions

Comment: First make sure if you getting any results from the getSpreadsheets() method by using this line of code:  print_r(count($spreadsheetFeed)); If you don't see any results make sure you shared the sheets with the client email in order to get it. There might also be a possibility of entering the sheet names wrong.

Comment: Thank you,  but i already printed $spreadsheetFeed and getting 0 as count... n i wont share any sheets... sheet name is right.... any other suggestions

Comment: So if the spreadsheet feed shows 0 count there is nothing returned from the service.

Comment: But i'm able to access the sheets data when i generated access token using web application credentials manually... but in that token was expires very fastly... so i opted to service account and in this i'm getting this error is their any other issue in my code?? or any other process to refreshing the access token with web application... any other suggestions...

Comment: Access tokens expire after about 1 hour - use the refresh token to get a new access token. The token comes with an expire time, so you can check if it has expired or not. - I had the same problem, OAuth2 is not easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it... the issue is about i didn't share my spreadsheet... when i shared my spreadsheet with client email then i'm able to insert records into the desired sheets... now i'm able to access every sheet,insert,delete everything...

So, when ever anyone got this problem just share your sheet with your client email.

Comment: Great answer! Got stuck at same spot. Thank You!

Comment: Can't thank you more! Exactly the same problem and a perfect solution. Thank you!